# How to get Internal IP of node by hostname

Tags: kubernetes

**The situation is:**

I am trying to deploy HDFS on Kubernetes. I am using DaemonSet to start one datanode on one node and the network mode for the pod is `hostNetWork`. In HDFS, datanodes and namenodes communicate by hostname. But now, if I add a new node to k8s cluster, existed nodes cannot get the internal IP of the new node by the hostname of the new node.

**That is,** I want to get node's Internal IP by hostname. Could kube-dns do this now ? Or using some other method to scale nodes for HDFS cluster on k8s.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reference

[Expose Pod Information to Containers Through Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/)

You can get the node name, node IP where a pod is deployed as below.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: hdfs-pod
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
```

As in [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods), you can then use the pod IP or name ,and namespace to query the K8S internal DNS.

> When enabled, pods are assigned a DNS A record in the form of “pod-ip-address.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local”

---

### Statefulset

How about considering using [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)? Each pod gets a specific name and based on the name, able to assign a specific role e.g. name node.

Just quickly search and found several articles on HDFS with K8S/StaefulSet.

- https://blog.hasura.io/getting-started-with-hdfs-on-kubernetes-a75325d4178c
- [Easiest HDFS cluster in the world with kubernetes](https://gist.github.com/polvi/34ef498a967de563dc4252a7bfb7d582)
- [Repository holding configuration files for running an HDFS cluster in Kubernetes](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/kubernetes-HDFS/blob/master/charts/hdfs-namenode-k8s/templates/namenode-statefulset.yaml)

Comment: Thanks. You give me some options I could try. And now I can pass the Pod's IP to internal config file of hadoop. I will check you answer after I try it and give a feedback to you. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi that is pod ip. So how can we get *node* ip? Thanks!